# Android download HLS

Tags: android, download, offline, http-live-streaming

i am trying to download a hls file using the HLSDownloader, but i am not getting the best results yet. My code:

```
// Main download function
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        downloadHls(VIDEO_URL);
        return null;
      }
    };
    asyncTask.execute();
```

...

```
  // This is the main tool to download hls
  private HlsDownloader hlsDownloader;
  private void downloadHls(String masterHLS) {


    hlsDownloader = getHlsDownloader(masterHLS);

    try {
      hlsDownloader.download(this);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

  private HlsDownloader getHlsDownloader(String mediaPlaylistUri) {

    File downloadFolder = new File(getFilesDir(), "video_id_2");

    SimpleCache cache = new SimpleCache(downloadFolder, new NoOpCacheEvictor());
    DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory factory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("ExoPlayer", null);

    CacheDataSource cacheDataSource =
            new CacheDataSource(cache, factory.createDataSource(), CacheDataSource.FLAG_BLOCK_ON_CACHE);

    // Create a downloader for the first variant in a master playlist.
    return new HlsDownloader(
            Uri.parse(mediaPlaylistUri), new DownloaderConstructorHelper(cache, factory));
  }
```

It seems the download starts and i am getting the progress of the downloading, but i can not access the downloaded file (maybe not exists), so i do not know if i am coding well. Some help it would be appreciated.

**EDITED:**

Currently i've got the download in multiple chunks (i forgotten to add the write permission in the manifest) all named like *.ve.exo extension files, but i do not know how to play them, any idea?

Comment: Hi @Billyjoker did you find any solution for playing the downloaded content ? as I am having the same problem